# Hot reload not working for Razor page VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages, hot-reload, .net-6.0

[image]

I just installed Visual studio2022 and create a project.NET6 web application with Razor page.
But I found that Hot re-load doesn't work even for little changes("TEST" to "TEST1" in screenshot) on Index.cshtml but error popup said "Edits were made which cannot be compiled.
So I had to re-build the project to see the changes.
But somehow it works when I use start without debugging.

Could anyone please help on this.

- currently I have both VS2019 and VS2022 installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that his is the *best* solution, but you can disable edit and continue so that you don't keep getting prompted. Go to Options->Debugging->General and unselect the 'Enable Edit and Continue and Hot Reload' option. Obviously if you want Edit and continue you may not want this as your solution.
[VS options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aLo7.png)